# manage.py shell and relative imports

Tags: django

I'm trying to load the following Python file with "manage.py shell". The manage.py script is in a parent directory and I'm using execfile('forms.py') from the directory containing the script.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Profile

class ProfileSearchForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['name']
```

This fails because of the explicit relative import:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "forms.py", line 2, in <module>
    from    .models         import    Profile
ImportError: No module named models
```

but if I switch to implicit relative import, it works:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from apps.myprofile.models import Profile

class ProfileSearchForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['name']
```

My problem is that I thought that explicit relative imports are a *good thing* (see Two Scoops), and I still think they are.

But now I need a workaround with manage.py.

Answer (score 2):

you need to change the current directory before the relative import in python shell. So this may works:

```
import os
os.chdir('apps/')
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Profile
```

Comment: I get a "No such file or directory" error. And when I enter:

import os
print(os.getcwd() + "\n")

I get the directory that contains the Python source file. Also, I'm using "execfile('forms.py')", which executes from the directory containing forms.py.